# Check if action returned View or Redirect in ActionFitler

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, action-filter

How do I check if an action returned `View()` or `Redirect()` in a custom `ActionFilter`? I need to check this as my `ActionFilter` populates the `ViewBag` with extra stuff. But if it's a redirect it is not needed.

## Example

### Controller Action

```
[MyActionFilter]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid())
        return View();
    else
        return Redirect("foo");
}
```

### Action Filter

```
public class MyActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // do something before the action executes
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (returned View)
            context.Controller.ViewBag.Foo = "Bar";
        else
            // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

Using an `ResultFilter` instead gave me access to the returned type. I also had to change from the after action to the before action as changing the result in the after action generally isn't allowed.

```
public class MyActionFilter : IResultFilter
{
    public void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ViewResult)
            context.Controller.ViewBag.Foo = "Bar";
        else
            // do other stuff
    }

    public void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ActionExecutedContext has an ActionResult.  You could check whether the ActionResult is a ViewResult or RedirectResult/RedirectToRouteResult in your OnActionExecuted.

Comment: It doesn't have an `ActionResult`. It does have a `Result` though. But it's always `null` and shouldn't be changed in this case as setting Result will short-circuits execution of the action method and subsequent action filters.